# How to find hidden filename that is 2 or 3 characters long

Tags: files, find

I want to find a hidden file with a name that is 2 or 3 characters long on a Linux machine.

I tried:

```
ls .?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]
ls .??[a-zA-Z]
```

I also tried `find . -name "???"` and `find . -name "??"` but it only shows filenames with 3 and 2 characters respectively.

Answer (score 1):

A filename that is hidden always starts with a dot.  A hidden filename that is two characters long, including the initial dot, would be matched by `.?`, while `.??` would match hidden filenames that are three characters long.

Assuming that you want names of *regular files*, not directories and other filetypes, then you would be able to use

```
find . -type f \( -name '.?' -o -name '.??' \)
```

This would find regular files in or below the current directory whose names are hidden and two or three characters long.

If you're using the `bash` shell, and are only interested in names in the current directory:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for name in .? .??; do [[ -f $name ]] && printf '%s\n' "$name"; done
```

This would loop over all the names that matches either of the two patterns (if there are any), and print out the ones that corresponds to regular files or symbolic links to regular files.

Setting the `nullglob` shell option in `bash` ensures that a pattern is removed completely if it doesn't match any names, rather than remain unexpanded.

By also setting the `extglob` shell option in `bash`, the two patterns `.?` and `.??` could be combined into `.@(?|??)` (or possibly `.??(?)`, but that's a bit obfuscated).

In the `zsh` shell, you can make the pattern only match regular files by means of a glob qualifier, and therefore don't need that loop:

```
printf '%s\n' .(?|??)(.)
```

Here, the `(.)` is the globbing qualifier that restricts the matching of names to only regular files.

Comment: Can I look for 2 or 3 characters with the help of ls and/or echo cmd?

Comment: @Soham Not in `bash` if you only want regular files. You would need a loop, as I've shown.

Comment: Or `printf '%s\n' .(?|??)(-.)` if you want that test of file type to be done after symlink resolution like with the `[[ -f $name ]]` approach.

Answer (score 0):

GNU `find` version 4.6.0 in Bash CentOS 8:

```
find . -type f -name '.??' -o -name '.???'
```

That will find hidden files with either two or three characters.

If you are counting the `.` as one of the characters:

```
find . -type f -name '.?' -o -name '.??'
```

Comment: Can I look for 2 or 3 characters with the help of ls and/or echo cmd?

Comment: @Soham No, this is not possible.